# Attributes set in RequestContextHolder lost after response is returned

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have exposed a service in SpringBoot and I am storing few attributes in RequestContextHolder. In one of my APIs , I have to do some activity asynchronously.The application accepts a request and creates a new thread for performing the activity and returns the response immediately. I pass the RequestContextHolder object to the thread as well.The thread tries to fetch the attributes from RequestContextHolder and it looks like it is null after the response is sent. If I return the response after thread completes execution , the value is available in thread. I am assuming RequestContextHolder is tied to HTTPRequest and it is lost when the response is returned. Is my assumption correct? If so , how can I handle this scenario?

*org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder*

Comment: The request is stored in ThreadLocal variable so by the time your async task is executed that variable can have another request or nothing. Just get the needed attributed before the execution and pass to your task.

Comment: Thanks @YevheniiMelnyk. So will the variable be destroyed when the response is returned?

Comment: yes the RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes() is called after the request is processed. RequestContextFilter is responsible for this by default in Spring Boot App.

Comment: Thanks @YevheniiMelnyk. I created a thread local variable and am storing the values that I need. If you can post it as an answer , I'll accept it.

Comment: I haven't got your your point, but it is unsafe to use threadlocal to store anything when processing data from another thread. Just get params before execution and pass them to constructor of execution task. Or make anonymous Callable and use it as a clousure to the already retrieved values but not to the ThreadLocal. You can also jsut return callable from controller and spring will handle result asynchronously. It can help if yoy tell what kind of async execution is used and what for.

Comment: @YevheniiMelnyk, I have a backend interceptor that intercepts all the backend SOAP and REST calls and logs the request and response for auditing purposes. I have few parameters that are stored as attributes in RequestContextHolder. I need to store these along with request and response in order to identify the related messages after it is stored. I wanted to do this in an async fashion. I passed the RequestContextHolder to newly created thread but as I mentioned it seems to be getting reset after request is done. Now I have created a threadlocal class in the newly created thread.

Comment: I am using the hashmap defined in ThreadLocal object to retrieve values in my interceptor. I am destorying this Threadlocal object after audit logging is performed. Please can you help in letting me know if this implementation is unsafe and also can you help explain how? Thank you very much for your help. appreciate it!!

Comment: Imagine the situation. 1) Server gets a request and starts processing in thread-1; (2) you create threadlocal for thread-1 holding the attributes you need; (3) you spawn a new thread, lets say it is thread-2 and pass threadlocal with your map into this thread; (4) a new request is accepted by server and the processign started in thread-1 again. The threadlocal is overwritten. If the thread-2 hasn't done its work regarding the threadlocal map, than it's going to have attributes from the second request but was spawn by the first one.

Comment: Solution: user RequestContextHolder for you interceptor and logic until you create a new thread. Before creating new thread use RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() and pass them to the new thread. Htis way there will be no thread misunderstanding and you can use RequestAttributes(actually a request) as a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Spring Boot Application RequestContextFilter sets the request to RequestContextHolder where it is stored as a thread local variable and cleans it after controller returns. It is not right way to use RequestContextHolder as an argument for another thread because its content can change during processing.

Use the actual request before starting new concurrent task by RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() which contains all the attributes set and is just a plain object without ThreadLocal underneath.

Comment: Thank you very much @Yevhenii Melnyk. Thanks for you response to my answer as well. I was trying to run a test , will request your help after I run it.